# Android test recording for third party app and webview support

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, android-webview, android-espresso-recorder

Recently I came across the Android Test Recording. - http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/test-recorder. It looks very interesting, i tried to play with my app.

I have couple of questions.

1. Can it record/generate code the tests done on third party app?
2. My testing app has webview inside. When i tried interacting with the webview it didn't generate the code. Does espresso test
   recording support the interaction with webview? If yes, what i have
   to do to enable auto-generate code for interaction with webview.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Pros of Espresso Test Recorder -
1. Allow Us to create effective UI based Test Cases with user interactions.
2.We can capture assertions and interactions without accessing app's structure directly which increases execution speed and optimizes test case.
3.It saves lot of time to search for locators and then writing test cases.
4. It supports multiple assertions making more reliable test cases.

Cons of Espresso Test Recorder -
1. Currently does not Support Recording of WebViews interactions. (To write WebView Interactions [Click Here](http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/02/testing-web-views-using-espresso-web.html))
2.  Once We complete Recording once for next time Recording it launches the app there is no API to control such behavior.
3. Cannot record Assertions for Toast Messages

For Learning how to Record Test Case in Details [Click here](http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/09/record-test-cases-using-espresso-test.html)

Comment: the same status remains for test recorder still today.